# problems with declaring variables in classes c++

Tags: c++, class

Lately I was working on a simple game and the game structure required me to declare many types of objects... and to make working with functions easier, I made a parent class for all of the other classes. this is a part of the entire code(simplified):

```
int q=500;
struct ship
{
    int x,y;
    bool dec=0;
};
struct enemysol : public ship
{
    int life=100,y=0,x;
    bool dec=0;
    void declare()
    {
        dec=1;
        x=10+rand()%(getmaxx()-20);
        life=100;
        y=0;
    }
};
int next(ship main[])   //finding next undeclared sol
{
    int i=1;
    while(main[i].dec)
    {
        i++;
        if(i==q)
            return -1;
    }
    return i;
}
```

The problem is that the `next` function will return `i` even if `enemysol.dec=1`
this code worked when I hadn't declared `ship`, but the project would have been very confusing and large if I didn't declared it..

Comment: Please, notice that you have two dec properties. One is ship::dec and the other is enemysol::dec. Using the next function with "main" and accessing "dec" gets ship::dec instead of what you expect. Remove "dec" from "enemysol" and try again :).

Comment: I tried writing 
    void declare()
    {
        enemysol::dec=1;
        ...
    }
but it didn't work. still, thanks for answering

Comment: @OMID Please read the comment from The Marlboro Man again, especially the first few words about *two* properties with the same name, and about *removing* one of them.

Comment: It's allright, take it easy... Let's see, using inheritance (struct enemysol : public ship) means that everything inside of "ship" will be already into "enemysol", right?. There's no need to redeclare "dec" in "enemysol" since it's already on "ship". When "enemy" wants to access "dec" all it needs to do is name it like "dec=1". Think of it as "enemysol" being the sum of "enemysol" and all that was in "ship": thus you don't need two "dec" (that is, delete entirely the one from "enemysol" and forget about it).

Comment: Notice that all that is being said is "sketchy": inheritance is a more complicated topic but considering you are using only public properties it's allright (just not "academia" material).

Comment: You have slicing issue with `int next(ship main[])`, it should be `int next(ship* main[])` (or `int next(const std::vector<ship*>& main)` and maybe replacing pointer by smart pointer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the wrong way to initialize the member variables of your `enemysol` class.

When you write:

```
int life=100,y=0,x;
bool dec=0;
```

you declare new member variables, which have the same name than the x, y and dec that you already have in `ship`.  So everytime you use x, y or dec in your enemysol class, you don't refer to the ship variables as these are hidden.

The right way of doing it would be something like:

```
struct enemysol : public ship
{
    int life;  // define only additional member variables not already in ship
    enemysol()  // constructor 
        : y(0), dec(false), life(100)   // init members
    {
    }
    void declare()
    {
        dec=1;
        x=10+rand()%(getmaxx()-20);
        life=100;
        y=0;
    }
};
```

Comment: That's more like it :).